# Correct way of initializing a Boolean

Tags: java

How a Boolean instance has to be initialized?

Is it

```
Boolean b = null;
```

or

```
Boolean b = new Boolean(null);
```

Which one is the correct coding practice?

Comment: I would say the first. The second one kinda makes no sense...but thats just me.

Comment: Why have a null boolean in the first place anyway ?

Comment: In a place where I couldn't find whether it is true or false

Comment: new Boolean(null) is terrible practice, avoid it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is correct if you want a `null` `Boolean`.

Personally I don't like having `null` values and prefer to use `boolean`, which cannot be `null` and is `false` by default.

In order to understand what the second statement does you need to understand about Java primitive wrappers. A `Boolean` is simply an object wrapper around a `boolean`; when you declare directly:

```
Boolean b = false;
```

There is some autoboxing going on and this is essentially equivalent to writing

```
Boolean b = Boolean.FALSE;
```

If you declare a `new Boolean` then you create a new and separate `Boolean` object rather than allowing the compiler to (possibly) reuse the existing reference.

It rarely (if ever) makes sense to use the constructor of the primitive wrapper types.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no need to create a new object for Boolean. 
This is what javadoc says

> Note: It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. Unless a new instance is required, the static factory valueOf(boolean) is generally a better choice. It is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance.

Comment: @Axel, I always rely on autoboxing, I quoted javadoc just to explain the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

○`Boolean b = new Boolean(null);` use `Boolean(String)` ctor and set `b` internal boolean value to `false` and is different to set `b` reference to null.

```
Boolean b = null;
System.out(b.boolValue()); throws a NullPointerException
```

but

```
Boolean b = new Boolean(null);
System.out(b.boolValue()); will print `false`
```

If you need only two-state value (a boolean) use a primitive boolean; if you need a three-state object (`null, true, false`) use `Boolean` object and set object reference - as in first example - to `null`

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct declaration

```
Boolean b = null;
```

This is constant creation and it will go to constant pool memory. You need to use `==` operator to compare two boolean constants.

```
Boolean b = new Boolean(null);
```

This is object creation  and it will go to Heap memory.You need to use `.equals()` method to compare two boolean objects.